# Sharing JUnit tests between client and server

Tags: java, gwt, junit, gwttestcase

Hello fantastic people!

I am developing a java module which will be used both on the server, and on the client (GWT).

I want to write a library of unit tests, and then simply create wrappers to run the tests on the client and on the server. This way, I can gurentee that the code behaves correctly on both, without having to write separate unit tests for each.

However, I see that there is no native support for JUnit in GWT and that GWTTestCase has to be used.

I was hoping someone might have a clever solution that would allow me to do this.

Thanks,

Casey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `GWTTestCase` returns `null` from `getModuleName()`, it'll be run as a simple JUnit test. The idea is thus to have 2 classes, one extending the other and overriding `getModuleName()`.

FYI, this is the exact technique used by GWT itself in its unit-tests; for instance for RequestFactory or AutoBeans; for instance [`RequestFactoryTest`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/client/RequestFactoryTest.java#223) which extends `GWTTestCase` and [`RequestFactoryJreTest`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/RequestFactoryJreTest.java) which extends `RequestFactoryTest`, overriding `getModuleName()` to return `null` as well as the way the tests are setup.